# How to change the font on the home page of a Magento website?

Tags: magento, web, text

I have looked everywhere in admin at static blocks and under system config and cannot find this (see attached), text anywhere.  All I want to do is to change text to all caps make it bold so that "Advanced Search" option is more visible.  Where do you think this setting is hidden.

[image: Screen Shot of the Text I want to Change]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The search bar of Magento is not created in a static block, and its text is not configurable directly in the back office. You'll have to dig into the code to find its CSS class, and add the modifications to the `styles.css` file of your theme. Magento is a framework designed to be highly customizable, but primarily by coding. Even for simple text changes, you'll need to take a tour in the source files of your website.